# Posting a complete model object to the controller when only few attributes are used in a form

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping, spring-form

I've read somewhere that for spring mvc, it is a expected behavior to get back NULL in case a form does not contain all the attributes of the model object set by the @ModelAttribute annotiation. S how can I use forms that don't have all the fields of the model object and still recieve the whole but updated object back to the post method of the controller.

A short example code of my intention:

Part of the controller:

```
....

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editPost(Model model, @PathVariable Integer id) {
        model.addAttribute("editPost", bPostService.getPost(id));
        return "editPost";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editProcessPost(Model model, @PathVariable Integer id, @ModelAttribute BPost editPost) {
        bPostService.updatePost(editPost);
        model.addAttribute("posts", bPostService.getPosts());
        return "redirect:/";
    }

....
```

The entity mapped by hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sometable")
public class BPost {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "anothertext")
    private String anothertext;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Part of the JSP view:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="editPost" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/secure/post/edit/${editPost.id}">
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>title:</td>
        <td><form:input path="title"></form:input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>description:</td>
        <td><form:input path="description"></form:input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text:</td>
        <td><form:input path="text"></form:input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input value="Edit" type="submit"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form:form>
```

As you can see the "anothertext" attribute is not used on the JSP, but I wan't it unchanged returned to the POST method of the controller. Is that possible?

I know some one probably already asked this question, but I cant find the answer to that.

Thank!

Comment: Store the object in the session using `@SessionAttributes` or create a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method which retrieves the object before each request handling method.

Comment: You could also keep the extra attributes as hidden input fields in the form but Deinum's way is a much better solution.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried `@ModelAttribute` annotation, but it didn't work. Which method do I have to annotated it like that, the GET or POST method?

Comment: Neither. A method that returns the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not want to use the entity as a form backing object which could have security implications. For example an malicious request could be forged to set some unwanted properties.

Therefor it's better in general to create a explicit form backing object for each form to process. It will require you to write more code but it also negates some common problems (like the one you're having).

When using a form backing object your handler looks more like:

*Note that I altered the `BPost` argument to `BPostForm`.*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editProcessPost(Model model, @PathVariable Integer id, @ModelAttribute BPostForm editPost) {

    // fetch the original post
    BPost post = bPostService.findById(editPost.getId());

    // set the properties
    post.setTitle(editPost.getTitle());
    post.setDescription(editPost.getDescription());
    post.setText(editPost.getText());

    // update
    bPostService.updatePost(post);

    model.addAttribute("posts", bPostService.getPosts());
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

*P.s. Using `bPostService.getPosts()` to add posts to the model and immediately return a redirect seems rather pointless ;)*

### [EDIT] Validation

Your form backing object can be validated using declarative validation using the Hibernate annotations or settings a custom validator in the `WebdataBinder`.

#### Hibernate annotations

When using the Hibernate annotations you can place any annotation on a field or getter. For these validations to kick in you'll need to do two things.

1. Register a validator bean `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean`.
2. Annotate the form backing object's argument in your handler with `@valid`.

Example: `public String editProcessPost(Model model, @PathVariable Integer id, @ModelAttribute @Valid BPostForm editPost, BindingResult result)`

Note that using validation needs a `BindingResult` to be present in the argument list and it needs to be directly after the backing object. This `BindingResult` will be a container for all validation errors.

#### Custom validator

A custom validator is a bit more work. You will need to write your own first.

`MyPostValidator extends org.springframework.validation.Validator`

After writing the validator you can add it to the `WebDataBinder`.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new MyPostValidator());
}
```

Comment: Very good point about security, so how is validation done in this case? Is validation by annotating the BPostForm object possible?

Comment: Either by using declarative validation using the hibernate annotations or setting a custom validator in the WebDataBinder. I could provide an example later if you want.

Comment: Added some explaination on how to handle validation. If validation is straight forward it's probably best to stick with Hibernate annotation and `@valid`. If validation needs to be more complex I strongly recommend having a custom validator.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier than this actually....I've been using this method for years

In your Controller class do the following:

```
// this method gets called by Spring after the GET/POST request but before the // binding of request parameters...
// for POST requests, we want the enity
@ModelAttribute("formName") // <---- Note the attribute name...this is    important
public Object getFormBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) {
   if(!request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
        return null;
   }

   // find primary key
   String id = request.getParameter("id");

   return serviceObject.getMyEntity(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String editProcessPost(@PathVariable Integer id,      @ModelAttribute("formName") BPostForm editPost) {

   // editPost is the fully populated entity from the DB after request params
   // have been bound to it.

   myService.save(editPost);

   return "whatever....";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Bart if possible replace the usage of entity pojo to form pojo directly in the jsp. If you want to continue with the existing approach you can use those fields as hidden parameters.

```
<form:hidden path="anothertext"/>
```

So when the form is getting submitted this value will be set automatically.

Here you may have another 2 issues.

**Hidden Field with another value**

Suppose you want to keep it as hidden value, but value should be different, then you can use like below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="anothertext" value ="{object.value}">
```

where object is any object available in the view scope.

**Hidden Field As Object**
What if you have have anothertext as object instead of plain text. For example if it is a User object with id and name as value and you have used like below under your entity

```
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ownerName", referencedColumnName = "name")
    private User owner;
```

In that case you have to use two values as hidden parameters. The id field of the object and the linking field (here it is name)

So it will go like below.

```
<form:hidden path="owner.id"/>
<form:hidden path="owner.name"/>
```

While persisting this back, hibernate will automatically merge with existing user from db with same id.