# Spring mvc model Which better : adding the whole object or adding its attributes one by one to the model?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to figure which solution is better to optimize server performance.

Solution 1 :

```
ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("view-name");
Student student = new Student();
// assuming Student object has a lot of     attributes
modelView.addObject("student", student);
```

Solution 2 :

```
Student student = new Student(); 
modelView.addObject("firstname", student.getFirstName());
modelView.addObject("lastname", student.getLasttName());
modelView.addObject("age", student.getAge());
```

The model is going to be used on a Freemarker page, so the real question is if calling a getter in Java is better then calling a getter on Freemarker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question with another question, are you experiencing performance issues?

With the small amount of data shown, there shouldn't be a difference with how performant either solution is.  With that in mind, the first solution is more readable.  Passing the entire object allows your GUI to change use more fields on the Student object without causing an error with a missing field if you forget to add one manually.

On teams that I've been on, we create separate GUI classes with a subset of the data that will be needed on the page.  This keeps fields such as a password hash from being accessible.  An example would be to create a StudentUI object taking Student in as a constructor parameter and setting the necessary fields.

Comment: I am already using separate GUI ( representations of my objects) and am not experiencing performance issues for now because am working in a very large project and I am trying to build a weel based application to avoid problems on the future. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Solution number one is the better choice. 
I think that it is customary to do so: passing your whole object "student" if you are going to use most of his fields in the "freemarker page". In cases that you need only one(or few, it depends on the size of the object) you can use Solution number two.

Answer (score 0):

> You might not want to use the entity as a form backing object which could have security implications. For example an malicious request could be forged to set some unwanted properties.
>
> Therefor it's better in general to create a explicit form backing object for each form to process. It will require you to write more code but it also negates some common problems (like the one you're having).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22281697/3365426